# Select From Multiple tables without joining them SQLAlchemy

Tags: python, sql, join, sqlalchemy

I want to select only One column from another table joined with another one, the join of these two have to be combined (not joined) with the join of another two tables.

To be clearer :

I have two tables :

```
     A                      B
-------------         -----------
 id   | value_a         id  | value_b
  1   |  'abc'           1  |   'xtz'
  2   |  'cde"           2  |  'cfss'
```

These two tables are joined then `combined` not joined (I don't know if the term is correct) with the join of `A` and a new table `C`.

```
     C                      
-------------         
 id   | value_c        
  1   |  'ccc'          
  2   |  'cdd'
```

So I want to do something like this :

```
i = A.join(B,B.c.id==A.c.id)
j = A.join(C,C.c.id== A.c.id)
select = select([A.c.value_a, B.c.value_b, C.c.value_c])\
.select_from(i,j).where(all_filters) #all_filters are some filters I create dynamically
```

but `select_from(i,j)` doesn't work, it produces the error :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "scr.py", line 230, in   &lt;module&gt;
    .select_from(i,j).where(all_filters)
TypeError: &lt;lambda&gt;() takes exactly 2 arguments (3 given)
```

HELP PLEASE

Comment: i don't understand how you get the values for table C. pls explain

Comment: Table C is an existing table in my database, I want to do join between A and B, another join between A and C ==> then finally combine these two join inside one query, am I not clear?